# Passing list of object from client to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, dojo

I am facing an issue while retrieving data from client to controller.

I got **400 Bad Request** error and I cannot find the reason for it.

**I am using dojo gridx here and this is the js file**

```
function goToReviewTargetsPage(){
    var gridSelectedData = JSON.stringify( dijit.byId("geneGridNodeforSelectTargets").store.data);

    dojo.xhrPost({
        url : contextPath + '/updateGeneData.htm',
        handleAs: 'json',
        headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }, 
        applyAroundAdviceOnLoad : true,
        preventCache : true,
        content : 
        {
            "selectedTargetsData" : gridSelectedData
        },
        load : function(data) 
        {
          \\do something
        },
        error : function(error) 
        {
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

**The json data in gridSelectedData mentioned in above js is:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"ABL1","diseases":[{"id":1,"diseaseName":"CANCER"}],"SV":true,"CNV":true,"SNP":true},{"id":2,"name":"ALK","diseases":[{"id":1,"diseaseName":"CANCER"}],"SV":false,"CNV":true,"SNP":true},{"id":3,"name":"BLA","diseases":[{"id":1,"diseaseName":"CANCER"}],"SV":false,"CNV":false,"SNP":true},{"id":4,"name":"ALS","diseases":[{"id":2,"diseaseName":"LUNGS"}],"SV":false,"CNV":true,"SNP":true}]
```

**This is the code from the controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateGeneData", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Gene> getSelectedGenes(@RequestBody Gene[] genes,
    HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    List<Gene> geneList = new ArrayList<>();
    // do something
    return geneList;
}
```

**Gene.java (POJO)**

```
public class Gene {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private boolean SNP = false;
private boolean SV = false;
private boolean CNV = false;
Set<Disease> diseases = new HashSet<Disease>();
 //getters and setters
}
```

**This is the Request Header**

`Accept:*/*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
 ajaxRequest:true
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Encoding:UTF-8
 Content-Length:795
 Content-Type:application/json
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`

**The payload is:**

```
[{id: 1, name: "ABL1", diseases: [{id: 1, diseaseName: "CANCER"}], SV: true, CNV: true, SNP: true},…]
```

Comment: did you checked server log ?? could you share same here ?

Comment: Yes. There's no issue in the server. However, I got the mistake. I was passing the json in the content (which was not necessary). There is a postData attribute in xhrPost which sends the json in the body of the request. But thank you for investing your time :)

Comment: how is it possible, if server responding with `400 Bad Request` and it is not logging anything related

Comment: Because 404 means that the server was able to communicate but was not able to find what was requested. So when i had put my json in content it wasn't in the request body (rather it was a parameter passed in the request). And when you post something using POST the data should be in the body.

Comment: I will update the code so that it is easy to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

change the post request from /updateGeneData.htm  on /updateGeneData and delete attributes produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,

Comment: The configuration file of spring is implemented in such a way that it will only accept url which contains ".htm"

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is wanting an array [] and you're passing it a list.  Your controller should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateGeneData", 
                produces MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public List<Gene> getSelectedGenes(@RequestBody List<Gene> genes) {
    List<Gene> geneList = new ArrayList<>();
    // do something
    return geneList;
}
```

I have found that sometimes I need to wrap my DTO in order for Jackson to work. This approach as worked for me in the past.

```
class Genes extends ArrayList<Gene> { }

@ResponseBody 
public List<Gene> getSelectedGenes(@RequestBody Genes genes) {
```

Comment: Hi, above is my updated code and it is working fine. However, I have tried your mentioned approach too, but as far as I remember, it was not working. I will try one more time and share the update soon. :)

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned I tried putiing @RequestBody List<Gene> genes in the getSelectedGenes() method argument. I get a LinkedHashMap like this: `[{id=1, name=ABL1, snp=checked, cnv=checked, sv=checked}, {id=2, name=ALK, snp=checked, cnv=checked, sv=disabled}, {id=3, name=BLA, snp=checked, cnv=disabled, sv=disabled}, {id=4, name=ALS, snp=checked, cnv=checked, sv=disabled}, {id=5, name=JAK3, snp=checked, cnv=checked, sv=checked}]`

Comment: So instead of that I put **@RequestBody Gene[] genes** in the argument and it worked